# Creating 'Empty' Records for Days of the Month Without Records

Tags: postgresql, calendar

I have a very simpl postgres (9.3) query that looks like this:

```
SELECT a.date, b.status
FROM sis.table_a a
JOIN sis.table_b b ON a.thing_id = b.thing_id
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.date) = 06
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM a.date) = 2015
```

Some days of the month of June do not exist in `table_a` and thus are obviously not joined to `table_b`.  What is the best way to create records for these not represented days and assign a placeholder (e.g. 'EMPTY') to their 'status' column?  Is this even possible to do using pure SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mark non-contiguous date ranges](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905064/mark-non-contiguous-date-ranges)

Comment: `cd.date` is in illegal reference. Please fix your sample code and provide Postgres version and the data type of your column `date`. Also: Does `table_b` always have all days?

Comment: Fixed.  Table_b contains status codes, one of which applies to every day in table_a.

Comment: The data type? is is `date` or `timestamp`?

Comment: a.date is type `date`

Comment: Is `table_a.date` unique? And do you need anything else from `table_a` than the column `date`?

Comment: `table_a.date` is not unique. I'm also not trying to add these 'empty' references to the table, just want to return them with the query.  `date` is the only feature I need to reference from `table_a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need `LEFT JOIN` and it looks like you also need `generate_series()` to provide the full set of days:

```
SELECT d.date
     , a.date IS NOT NULL AS a_exists
     , COALESCE(b.status, 'status_missing') AS status
FROM (
   SELECT date::date
   FROM   generate_series('2015-06-01'::date
                        , '2015-06-30'::date
                        , interval '1 day') date
    ) d
LEFT   JOIN sis.table_a a USING (date)
LEFT   JOIN sis.table_b b USING (thing_id)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Use [**sargable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) `WHERE` conditions. What you had cannot use a plain index on `date` and has to default to a much more expensive sequential scan. (There are no more `WHERE` conditions in my final query.)

Aside: don't use the basic type name (and reserved word in standard SQL) `date` as identifier.

Related (2nd chapter):

- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193688/postgresql-running-count-of-rows-for-a-query-by-minute/8194088#8194088)